# Clarification between charts being incompatible and smooth structures being "exotic"

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102028/what-is-the-significance-of-incompatible-coordinate-charts-for-a-manifold), $\mathbb{R}$ can be given the atlas $\mathcal{A} = \{f(x) = x : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ or the atlas $\mathcal{B} = \{g(x) = x^3 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

These are incompatible because there exist combinations of $f,g$ and their inverses which produce non smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, namely $f \circ g^{-1} = \sqrt[3]{x}$, so this fails to be a diffeomorphism.

Obviously $f(\mathbb{R}) = g(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces. Why does this not count as an "exotic line"?, which is precisely when we have homeomorphic objects but not diffeomorphic ones, the classification theorem says there can be no such thing as an exotic $\mathbb{R}$, since the line is $1$ dimensional and weird things can only happen in starting at dimension $4$.

Perhaps I am struggling to grasp the difference since I have not actually seen what an exotic differential structure looks like, I suppose they require all sorts of advanced constructions and can't be expressed with a nice example, so what makes being exotic so much more bad than just being incompatible?

Comment: Because $x\mapsto x^3$ (or $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]{x}$ depending on which way you go) is a diffeomormophism between your two lines $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.  An "exotic" differential structure means not diffeomorphic to the standard differential structure, not "identity is not a diffeomorphism".

Comment: Anyway, if you haven't seen it, all exotic $S^7$s are very easy to describe as [Brieskorn sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Brieskorn_spheres).

Comment: @user10354138 But the cube root is not differentiable at 0, so how is this a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Because you are using $g\colon x\mapsto x^3$ as the global chart in $\mathcal{B}$, and $g\circ\sqrt[3]{}\circ f^{-1}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$ which is of course $C^\infty$.  Hence $\sqrt[3]{}$ is a diffeomorphism $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Smooth structure is used in different ways. The most common definition of smooth structure is that it is a maximal smooth atlas. Unfortunately, smooth structure is also sometimes used to refer to the diffeomorphism type of a manifold and its smooth atlas. It is very easy to create unequal smooth structures of the first type (like was done in the comments above), but the second type is much harder because it is asserting that no diffeomorphism exists sending one atlas to the other.

Comment: @user10354138 I think I understand your example, but what is wrong with the following: I should be able to perform the same calculation done in the $\mathcal{A}$ atlas (it's an equivalence relation), so $x$ must also also be a diffeomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$, but $f \circ x \circ g^{-1} = \sqrt[3]{} $ which isn't smooth?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis I have no idea what you mean by the same calculation done in the $\mathcal{A}$-atlas.  $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ is not $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$ so you have no right to expect the identity on $\mathbb{R}$ to be a diffeo between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: What I mean is, when you verified that $g \circ \sqrt[3]{} \circ f^{-1}$ works as a smooth map, you were using that a map between manifolds $m : (M_1, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (M_2, \mathcal{B})$ (for us $M_1 = M_2 = \mathbb{R}$) is smooth iff $\psi_\mathcal{B} \circ m \circ \phi_{\mathcal{A}}^{-1}$ is smooth for chart maps $\phi, \psi$, but it also has to be true that $\phi_\mathcal{A} \circ m^{-1} \circ \psi_{\mathcal{B}}^{-1}$ is smooth if $m$ is a diffeomorphism right? You chose $m = x^3$ but I can also choose $m = x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing exotic here. Yes, the two atlases give us two distinct smooth structures, i.e. two distinct smooth manifolds with underlying topological space $\mathbb R$. Let us call them $\mathbb R_{id}$ and $\mathbb R_g$. But these smooth manifolds **are diffeomorphic**: In fact, $g : \mathbb R_g \to \mathbb R_{id}$ is a diffeomorphism since
$$\mathbb R \stackrel{g^{-1}}{\to} \mathbb R \stackrel{g}{\to} \mathbb R \stackrel{id}{\to} \mathbb R \phantom{x} , \phantom{x} \mathbb R \stackrel{id^{-1}}{\to} \mathbb R \stackrel{g^{-1}}{\to} \mathbb R \stackrel{g}{\to} \mathbb R$$
are the identity maps which are smooth.

See [$C^{\infty } $ diffeomorphism between 2 nonequivalent manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518141) .